# How to fix "index out of bounds" error with dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new data.frame with info from some others.

I've already tried to transform index series to array but in didn't seem to work, maybe because of my lack of knowledge.

```
import pandas as pd

def forma_base():
    dict_indices={"Escola":[],"Codigo da escola":[],"Formação ideal":[],
        "Alunos por turma":[],"Professores com formação superior":[],
        "Distorção idade-serie":[],"INSE":[],"Abandono":[],"Reprovação":[],
        "Matriculas no 3 ano":[],"Participação no Enem":[],
        "Media no Enem":[]}
    df_base=pd.DataFrame(dict_indices)

    return df_base


def preenche_escola():
    df_base=forma_base()
    bancos=importa_bancos()
    banco=bancos[0]

    for i in range(len(banco)):
        if banco["Dependência Administrativa"][i]=="Privada":
            continue
        else:
            df_base["Escola"][i].append(banco["Nome da Escola"][i])
            df_base["Codigo da escola"][i].append(banco["Código da Escola"][i])

    return df_base
```

> The output is "IndexError: index out of bounds".

Comment: I think iteration as you are doing it is not needed. Could you provide the data you have and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've set up that loop in the second function to check whether or not one line in another DataFrame `banco` is present. Another way to do it would be to dump the data in first and then do a selective drop of the rows.

```
def preenche_escola():
    df_base=forma_base()
    bancos=importa_bancos()
    banco=bancos[0] # I'm going to assume this extracts your desired DataFrame

    df_base["Escola"] = banco["Nome da Escola"]
    df_base["Codigo da escola"] = banco["Código da Escola"]
    df_base["Dependência Administrativa"] = banco["Dependência_Administrativa"]

    df_base = df_base[~df_base.Dependência_Administrativa.str.contains("Privada")]

    return df_base
```

And if you don't need the ["Dependência Administrativa"] column, just `df_base.drop(columns=["Dependência Administrativa"], inplace=True)` after.